# Align items horizontally in sinblings, without changing html structure

Tags: html, css

Like you can see from the snippet, there are 2 dynamically created flex div's (it can be more)

Is there a way to align items horizontally, on bigger screens, without changing html structure?

I'm loking for:

[image]

```css
.detail-card {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid rgb(222, 226, 230);
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}
.custom-checkbox-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  align-items: baseline;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 576px){
  .custom-checkbox-wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="detail-card">
  <h4>title</h4>
  <div class="custom-checkbox-wrapper">
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <label>First</label>
    </div>
    <p>Price: <span>50 €</span></p>
    <p>Name: <span>Name 1</span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-checkbox-wrapper">
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <label>Second second</label>
    </div>
    <p>Price: <span>60 €</span></p>
    <p>Name: <span>Some Name 2</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can change to `inline-flex` for bigger screens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `table-row` and `table-cell` to align rows like table's elements

```css
.detail-card {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid rgb(222, 226, 230);
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.detail-card h4 {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.custom-checkbox-wrapper {
  display: table-row;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.custom-checkbox-wrapper p,
.custom-checkbox-wrapper div {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 1rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  .custom-checkbox-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .custom-checkbox-wrapper p,
  .custom-checkbox-wrapper div {
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="detail-card">
  <h4>title</h4>
  <div class="custom-checkbox-wrapper">
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <label>First</label>
    </div>
    <p>Price: <span>50 €</span></p>
    <p>Name: <span>Name 1</span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-checkbox-wrapper">
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled">
      <label class="disabled" title="Second">Second second</label>
    </div>
    <p class="disabled">Price: <span>60 €</span></p>
    <p class="disabled">Name: <span>Some Name 2</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```